# Not displaying any picture

Tags: android, image

I am using Android studio 4.1.3 and i was trying to write my application.

The problem is, it doesn't run properly when you add pictures to your app.

For example, i have coded a splash screen and when i run it without any picture, it runs perfect but when you add any picture, the app will be crashed.

I have checked all the things you think but i have got nothing. I have checked the drawable, i have used ImageView, android:background but nothing happened.

Help me

Comment: Please provide the logs that you are getting during the crash

Comment: I use my phone as an emulator and i have had no problem until these days.